# Exclude a certain number from this regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that test for an input with max length of 5. My problem is I want to exclude the single digit of 2. If string contains only number "2", it should fail. How do I exclude number 2 in this regex? `/^([a-zA-Z,\d]){1,5}$/`

13425 - Match 
03277 - Match 
2 - Fail.

Comment: Maybe regex is not the right tool for the job...

Comment: To confirm, "5123" should match the regex, because the '2' is not the only character in the string, correct?

Comment: @ Perfectionsit , Thats correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A negative look-ahead assertion can do this for you

```
/^(?!2$)([a-zA-Z,\d]){1,5}$/
```

Comment: Thanks guys.. I tried to search for it before posting. would have never guessed this :)

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issu, i need to match all number with five degit except those :

  from 47893 to 47899

  23030 , 22060, 21037 and 21050

  To match all number with five degit :
  *`^\\d{5}$`*

  To exclude number from 47893 to 47899 :
  *`?!(^4789[3-9]$)`*

  3- To exclude other number :
  *`?!(23030|22060|21037|21050)`*

-->The final pattern : `(?!((^4789[3-9]$)|23030|22060|21037|21050))^\\d{5}$`